# Dynamically insert into MySQL table based on field value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am using the following code snippet to insert a record into another table in the same database

```
$data = array();
$data["Number"] = $values['Number'];
$data["Rider Name"] = $values['Rider Name'];
$data["Horse Name"] = $values['Horse Name'];
$data["Division"] = $values['Division'];
DB::Insert("Training", $data );
```

I have multiple tables I want to insert this data into, so I was wondering if there is a way, and how to accomplish it, of telling the code based on the value entered into `Division' field, which table to insert the data into?

For example:

- If 'Training' is entered into the 'Division' field > enter data into 'Training' table.
- If 'Novice A' is entered into the 'Division' field > enter data into 'Novice - A' table.
- If 'BN A' is entered into the 'Division' field > enter data int 'BN - A' table
- etc...

I'm not sure if this is possible or not, but if it is, could someone please give me some direction on how to possibly accomplish this please?

if-elseif code I used:

```
// Insert records into Division tables //

if($data["Division"] == $values['Training']){
$data = array();
$data["Number"] = $values['Number'];
$data["Rider Name"] = $values['Rider Name'];
$data["Horse Name"] = $values['Horse Name'];

DB::Insert("Training", $data );

} elseif($data["Division"] = $values['Novice A']){
$data = array();
$data["Number"] = $values['Number'];
$data["Rider Name"] = $values['Rider Name'];
$data["Horse Name"] = $values['Horse Name'];

DB::Insert("Novice - A", $data );

} elseif($data["Division"] = $values['Novice B']){
$data = array();
$data["Number"] = $values['Number'];
$data["Rider Name"] = $values['Rider Name'];
$data["Horse Name"] = $values['Horse Name'];

DB::Insert("Novice - B", $data );

} elseif($data["Division"] = 'BN A'){
$data = array();
$data["Number"] = $values['Number'];
$data["Rider Name"] = $values['Rider Name'];
$data["Horse Name"] = $values['Horse Name'];

DB::Insert("BN - A", $data );

} elseif($data["Division"] = 'BN B'){
$data = array();
$data["Number"] = $values['Number'];
$data["Rider Name"] = $values['Rider Name'];
$data["Horse Name"] = $values['Horse Name'];

DB::Insert("BN - B", $data );

} elseif($data["Division"] = 'Starter A'){
$data = array();
$data["Number"] = $values['Number'];
$data["Rider Name"] = $values['Rider Name'];
$data["Horse Name"] = $values['Horse Name'];

DB::Insert("Starter - A", $data );

} elseif($data["Division"] = 'Starter B'){
$data = array();
$data["Number"] = $values['Number'];
$data["Rider Name"] = $values['Rider Name'];
$data["Horse Name"] = $values['Horse Name'];

DB::Insert("Starter - B", $data );

} elseif($data["Division"] = 'Starter C'){
$data = array();
$data["Number"] = $values['Number'];
$data["Rider Name"] = $values['Rider Name'];
$data["Horse Name"] = $values['Horse Name'];

DB::Insert("Starter - C", $data );

} 

return true;
```

Comment: Having multiple tables with the same structure that hold the same information seems like the real problem to be solved here.  Why do you need that structure?

Comment: As @David has said, why not just put the data into a single db table and then use a table **field** to store the value of the **division** ? (actually I am sure your idea can be done by simple coding say using if-then-else or switch but this is not a preferred way to handle data)

Comment: @KenLee - this is for a scoring website, and each division needs to have a separate database to keep it easy.  I have tried using is-elseif statements, but in doing so, I either have all records being entered into the first database record, or the second record, no matter what I enter in the division record,

Comment: **I have tried using is-elseif statements** Would you please show the codes which you have attempted (using is-elseif statements). Thx. (By the way, are you using laravel framework ?)

Comment: @KenLee - didnt realize there was a typo they were if-elseif statements and I just added the code

Comment: This database design is completely unsustainable, and you are absolutely making things harder for yourself (if not now, then for sure in the near future). I would implore you to explore and implement third normal form and generally accepted best design practices before this gets completely out of hand. Every time a division is added/changed/removed you’re actually going to add a whole slew of if/else statements?

Comment: @esqew - I am only trying to do this for the 'registration process, so that when they enter all of the competitors they are all listed in the appropriate division, so when the person who enters the data, only has to click on edit to enter the scores, so they don't have to add each rider to that division.  just trying to make things easier for the scoring team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your elsif statements, all the elsif statements should use == instead of = as **comparison** operators (we are not doing value assignment, right ?)

For example:

```
elseif($data["Division"] = 'Starter B')
```

should be

```
elseif($data["Division"] == 'Starter B')
```

Please change all of them.

However, as @esqew has said, please normalize your database instead of using the current "split tables" design.

Comment: Thank you that worked.  not sure why it worked now, because I tried that before but I think I only tried with == in the first if statement, and just = with the elseif statements.  But really do appreciate your help.